# Finding k-th digit of a really large number

Tags: number-theory, exponentiation, python

I am given 4 inputs, **A, B, N** and **K** where $-1 \lt A - \sqrt{B} \lt 1$. From that, I need to calculate the number $X^N$ so that $X = A + \sqrt{B}$ and print the K-th digit from that number. The problem is, the number is humongous, the range of the input is $1 \le A, B \le 10^4$, $1 \le N \le 10^9$ and $1 \le K \le 4$. The regular exponentiation in python returns an OverflowError so I tried implementing it by myself but still I get a NaN somewhere since the number is so big. Here is the code I used:

```
from sys import stdin, stdout
from math import sqrt


def exp(x, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    k = x
    x = exp(x, int(n/2))
    x *= x
    if n%2 == 1:
        x *= k
    return x

A, B, N, K = [int(i) for i in stdin.readline().split()]

X = (A + sqrt(B))
X = exp(X, N)

k_th = int((X%(10**K))/(10**(K-1)))
stdout.write("%d\n" % k_th)
```

Is there an algorithm that can solve this type of problems? I thought on modular exponentiation but since $X$ is a real number and not an integer it didn't work.

You can see more details of this problem [here](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/2668).
One thing I was pointed out was that since:

$$-1 \lt A - \sqrt{B} \lt 1$$
$$-1(A + \sqrt{B}) \lt A^2 + B \lt A + \sqrt{B}$$
$$-X \lt A^2 + B \lt X$$

and since $A$ and $B$ are both positive integers, $A + \sqrt{B} \gt 0$

**Clarifications**

**A, B, N** and **K** are integers

I need the k-th least significant digit in decimal base of $\lfloor X^N \rfloor$

Comment: Are $A,B,N,K$ integers?

Comment: In what base? Is it the K-th digit from the right?

Comment: A, B, N and K are integers, I need the k-th least significant digit from the of floor(X^N)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't really clear, but in that case, it is 7 because $\lfloor X^N \rfloor = \lfloor 37.97 \rfloor = 37$, the first number is 7, if k instead was 2 the answer would be 3

Comment: The formerly referenced page says $1\le K \le 4$

Comment: Sorry about that, I will correct it above

Comment: Is this from a current mathematical competition? Site rules do not allow questions on competition problems until after the close date.

Comment: It's a from a closed competition it was on the regional level of the ICPC competition in Brazil, a month ago.